# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE)

Tags: php, mysql

> Full Error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ''
>   (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or
>   variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

It says that the error is on line 12. Here is what I have there:

```
$introduction="INSERT INTO Introduction (Title, Description)
VALUES ('$_POST[introtitle]','$_POST['introdescription']')";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/13935532#13935532 It's the quotes in `$_POST['introdescription']`

Comment: Not onto the more serious issue - this is highly vulnerable to SQL injection. You ought to be using parameterized queries via PDO or MySQLi.  [Read over this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) question and its answers.

Comment: You need to read up on [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and how to [properly escape data](http://bobby-tables.com/php) before you write **any** more SQL code.

Comment: I am using PHP's `<<<HEREDOC` syntax ever since PHP 8, when it's finally pretty, with closing tag `HEREDOC;` being allowed to be indented. I like how VSCode colours code depending on `<<<SQL`, `<<<HTML` or `<<<JAVASCRIPT` being used. So in my case this error occurred when I copied some newer code, to the older codebase with PHP 7. Therefore the error was one line before what the error log stated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have extra single quotes :

```
$introduction="INSERT INTO Introduction (Title, Description)
VALUES ('$_POST[introtitle]','$_POST[introdescription]')";
```

Comment: Any answer with `$_POST` in the query string is hazardously wrong. This is also incorrect because it won't interpolate correctly.

Comment: @tadman it's not my code ...so why do you downvote this ? This fix the error...may be he don't care for sql injection.

Comment: A) Your answer is incorrect. B) If you're posting code, it should be valid for a range of inputs, such as values like `My 'Title'`. Saying "someone doesn't care about SQL injection" is absolutely nuts.

Comment: I'm learning PHP and MySQL at the moment and so I'm starting off with the basics. I will look into the SQL injections once I get this to work! :D

Comment: @tadman A) The answer is correct B) If you do a script for yourself, sql injection is not relevant.

Comment: @user1804933 That's good to hear. It's extremely important to do this correctly because if you make a mistake the consequences can be catastrophic. This is how companies like Sony get their user databases "hacked" and could completely ruin your day if someone does this to you.

Comment: @tadman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/13935532#13935532 - no quote is needed if the whole string is between double quote : "In a double-quoted string, PHP will permit array key strings to be used unquoted, and will not issue an E_NOTICE."

Comment: @FabienTheSolution Fair enough. In that specific case I stand corrected, but without escaping this is still wrong.

Comment: Strange that the selected answer got downvote .... Another "SQL Injection" psycho out there...

Comment: the answer is relatively correct so i will up vote this.